# Calculating the derivative with limited info.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$G(x) := \int_x^{x^2} f(t) \ dt$$

Calculate G'(x).

I've made some progress by integrating by parts with f(t) = 1(f(t)) but I'm stuck now and don't know where to go.

Comment: Please do not deface your questions Sw James.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt.$$ Then $$G(x)=F(x^2)-F(x).$$

Now use the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: thank you. I can't believe it was this simple haha. I've worked it through now, thanks.

and thanks for cleaning my post up

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental theorem of calculus says that $$\frac d {dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) \, dt=f(b(x)) \,b'(x)-f(a(x))\, a'(x)$$